# docker systemctl problem about automatically execute shell script to add new service

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-container, systemctl

used jrei/systemd-ubuntu docker image, 
I made a container.
ref : https://hub.docker.com/r/jrei/systemd-ubuntu/dockerfile

my final goal is that add new service using systemctl and executing it when a container is booting.

So I had done 3 case of test as following.

1. excute /lib/systemd/systemd in a sh file

   ```
   !/bin/bash

   while true do

   /lib/systemd/systemd

   result=$(ps -ax|grep -v grep|grep systemd-journald)

   if [ "${#result}" -ne 0 ]

       then

           systemctl daemon-reload

           systemctl start gunicorn

           systemctl enable gunicorn

           break

       else

           echo "${#result}"

       fi 
   done
   ```

   result :  error occur

   msg : trying to run as user instance, but the system has not been booted with systemd.
2. add command in docker-compose.yml

   ```
   command:
           - /bin/bash/
            - /root/test.sh
   ```

   result :  error occur

   msg : trying to run as user instance, but the system has not been booted with systemd.
3. rebuild dockerfile based on jrei/systemd-ubuntu

   ```
   FROM jrei/systemd-ubuntu

   COPY service/* /etc/systemd/system/

   COPY test.sh /root/test.sh

   RUN chmod +x /root/systemctl_cmd.sh

   VOLUME [ "/sys/fs/cgroup" ]

   ENTRYPOINT ["/root/systemctl_cmd.sh"]
   ```

   result :  error occur

   msg : trying to run as  user instance, but the system has not been booted with systemd.

Even I had test it 3 times, I couldn't find any way.

So I hope to get any idea how I can run above commands.
And I want to know How I get the information about system booting status.
I think if I run systemctl command after finished booting state, it can be working.

any idea or tip are wellcoming.

Comment: Containers don't "boot"; they run one process only (and anything else that process cares to start).  I'd suggest avoiding systemd in a container if at all possible.  Typical Docker practice would be to just run `CMD ["gunicorn"]` in your Dockerfile and make that be the only process in the container.

Comment: I agree with David. "When in Rome, use docker best practices". Avoid the problem instead of trying to fix it - one container, one process, and aggregate a group of containers with docker-compose or your favorite docker orchestration tool.

Comment: I know if the service being zombie process, container doesn't detect the process status so can't reboot itself.
So I am considering systemctl service.
I know supervisor too. but systemctl is better. in my oppinion.
do you have any idea for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

1. you do not need to "start unicorn" if you just want to enable it. Just use "`systemctl enable --global foo.service`". If you want to have the service started along then syy "`systemctl enable --now foo.service`".
2. actually you do not need to enable the service when it shall be run in the container and to have it stop at the end. Just run the systemd daemon and use "systemctl" to ask the daemon to start the service.
3. Since "systemd" is a daemon, you need to push it to the background, so that the systemctl can find its communication socket. In order to have a correct shutdown, you need to make sure your shell script makes a "trap" on SIGINIT which comes from "docker stop".

After all: there are better examples on the internet, how you can use container like a virtual machine with systemd. That would include also the [docker-systemctl-replacement](https://github.com/gdraheim/docker-systemctl-replacement) project where you can also have a look into the [docker-systemctl-images](https://github.com/gdraheim/docker-systemctl-images) examples.